# Include .php file

Tags: php, include

I want to include environments.php in the employee.php folder.
First I included this way, but that simple didn't work.

```
include('../config/environments.php');
```

Map dir

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to move to levels up in your folder structure, try this:

```
include('../../config/environments.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to include `environments.php` file is

```
include( __DIR__ . '/../../environments.php' );
```

You need to go up from directory `loader` (first `..`) and than from `functions`. `__DIR__` variable is used because [CWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Current_working_directory) can be set to absolutely different location than where `employee.php` file is stored.